# IXmlSerializable change xml tag names

Tags: c#, ixmlserializable

I have class with collection as below

```
public class MyClass:IXmlSerializable
{
    int vesrion;
    private Collection<int> testcoll;
}
```

to serialize it I have written WriteXML as below

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{

    writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", this.vesrion.ToString());    

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Collection<int>));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, Testcoll);
 }
```

Now output xml have tag "ArrayOfInt" as for Testcoll. But I want to change this name to something different "MyCollection".

Please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute over the field, like this:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "MyCollection")]
private Collection<int> testcoll;
```

EDIT: @comments, missed those details, see below for answer that works (compiled and tested)

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Collection<int>), new XmlRootAttribute("MyCollection"));
serializer.Serialize(writer, Testcoll);
```

Comment: I don't think that would work as he's not serializing `MyClass` using the default XmlSerializer implementation.  It's coming out from appending a default XmlSerialization of type `Collection<int>`.

Comment: I am out of office now, I will try it tommorow and let you know. By looking at edited code, I think it would definatly work :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way that doesn't create a new XmlSerializer:

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteAttributeString("Version", vesrion.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    writer.WriteStartElement("MyCollection");
    foreach (int collint in Testcoll)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("int", collint.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```